# Create a graph if nodes are not continuous c++

Tags: c++, graph, undirected-graph

Consider this situation:
(undirected graph)
we dont have number of nodes but have the edges like 1<->3 , 6<->7, 3<->7. So how do we declare a graph using this?

Generally we have n that is no. of node and e edges but in this case we only have e edges and that too not continuous i.e. instead of 1,2,3,4(or zero indexed) we have 1,3,6,7.
I know we should use a map to convert these 1,3,6,7 values to 1,2,3,4 but how?

how we generally declare a graph

```
vector<int> adj[100000];
for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
{
  int u,v;
  cin>>u>>v;
  //need some mapping technique here to make this continuous
  adj[u].push_back(v);
  adj[v].push_back(u);
}

//iterate according to situation
```

Comment: A side note: instead of `vector<int> adj[100000]` consider to use `vector<vector<int>> adj(10000)` (no need for C style arrays in C++, plus your code requires a huge allocation on the stack).

Comment: No an adjacency matrix is not a vector, it has 2 dimensions So @wohlstad is right. Becaus that will only allocate memory for actual edges. Using a "C" style 2D array will over allocate (on the stack)

Comment: Or, if the matrix is not really dense, just use a `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried few combinations and this approach works well
**e-> no. of edges**

this approach maps the input vertices to respective values in map from 0 based index. Helpful to apply various algorithms directly without worrying about the input as much.

```
int i=0;
while(e>=0)
    {
        e--;
        int a1,a2;
        cin>>a1>>a2;
        //a1
        if(mp.find(a1)!=mp.end())
            a1 = mp[a1];
        else
        {
            
            mp[a1] = i;
            a1 = i;
            i++; 
        } 
        //a2  
        if(mp.find(a2)!=mp.end())
            a2 = mp[a2];
        else
        {
            
            mp[a2] = i;
            a2 = i;
            i++; 
        } 
        adj[a1].push_back(a2);
        adj[a2].push_back(a1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not relying on the input to specify the number of nodes.  Often the input is generated by a human being, and human beings are just terrible at counting.  That's why computers were invented.

Ignore the specified number of nodes and write code to count the nodes as you encounter them in the edge list.

For the same reason, take the "numbers" that identify the nodes that an edge connects in the input with suspicion.  They should be regarded as node labels, and you should maintain and assign a node index whenever a new label is encountered in the input.

Looking at your example, the input code should generate a data structure ( of whatever kind you prefer: adjacency matrix, neighbor list, maps, vectors ... there are several choices each with its pros and cons ) that captures this

| label | index |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |

with edges represented as

| src index | dst index |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |

Comment: your first approch was exactly what i have in mind that to update u and v when they arrive as an input from the user according to the map we have constructed. But can you code this up?

Comment: OK. My C++ code for constructing graphs using this technique can be seen at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder.  The cGraph class interface is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/main/src/cGraph.h.  The class is implemented here https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/main/src/cGraph.cpp  A detailed description of the design choices I made can be read at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/cGraph-Class-Design.

Comment: The rest of the github repo has code implementing many standard algorithms of graph theory.  A gentle introduction to the application that ties all this together can be read at https://ravenspoint.wordpress.com/2021/05/23/pathfinder/

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the matrix representation of a graph in this case -- especially if the vertex indices are very sparse.

Use adjacency lists. Since node indices are not necessarily contiguous, use some kind of map, either a map or a unordered map, to associate indices with their adjacency lists. (Also don't actually use "lists" which are inefficient on modern hardware. Use resizable arrays, in C++ `std::vector<T>`'s)

Code below, along with a depth-first traversal.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

class graph {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> impl_;
public:
    void insert_edge(int u, int v) {
        impl_[u].push_back(v);
        impl_[v].push_back(u);
    }

    std::span<const int> neighbors(int u) const {
        auto iter = impl_.find(u);
        if (iter != impl_.end()) {
            return iter->second;
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    }
};

void dfs(const graph& g, int u, std::unordered_set<int>& visited) {
    if (visited.find(u) != visited.end()) {
        return;
    }
    visited.insert(u);

    std::cout << u << "\n";

    for (auto v : g.neighbors(u)) {
        dfs(g, v, visited);
    }
}

int main() {

    graph g;
    g.insert_edge(1, 3);
    g.insert_edge(6, 7);
    g.insert_edge(3, 7);
    g.insert_edge(3, 42);

    std::unordered_set<int> visited;
    dfs(g, 1, visited);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code uses the node labels as integer keys into a map.  There are a couple of problems with doing that.  A. the user cannot label the nodes with meaningful names ( strings ).  B. Looking up nodes in the map will become slow when there are large numbers ( in my work I deal with graphs contain hundreds of thousands of nodes )

Comment: you can make the labels whatver you want and long as they can be keys to hash tables e.g. strings would work -- this is StackOverflow answer code not production software.

Comment: Strings will not work because your code construct a data structure keyed with ints std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> impl_

Comment: can use `std::unordered_map<T, std::vector<T>>` where T is whatever you want to use as keys/IDs. My mistake on the matrix thing.